# How to deploy grant permissions on Self-Hosted IR using Bicep

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-bicep

I'm trying to create a Bicep file that is capable of deploying RBAC for my environment. I'm currently able to deploy role assignments to resource groups and resource levels. The next thing I want to do is be able to grant permission for newly created Data Factory resources on my existing Self-hosted IR using Bicep.

[image]

Here are my attempts in code (attempt 1 and attempt 2):

```
param principalId string = ''
param roleDefinitionGuid string =''
param shirProperties object = {}

var roleAssignGuid = guid(principalId,roleDef.id)

resource roleDef 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions@2022-04-01' existing = {
  name: roleDefinitionGuid
}

resource rgIr 'Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2022-09-01' existing = {
  scope: subscription(shirProperties.subscriptionId)
  name: shirProperties.rg
}
resource df 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories@2018-06-01' existing = {
  scope: rgIr
  name: shirProperties.dfCentral
}

resource ir 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/integrationRuntimes@2018-06-01' existing = {
  parent: df
  name: shirProperties.irName
}

//Attempt 1
resource irContrib1 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
  name: roleAssignGuid
  scope: ir 
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: roleDef.id
    principalId: principalId
  }
}

//Attempt 2
resource irContrib2 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
  name: roleAssignGuid
  scope: '${df}/${ir}'
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: roleDef.id
    principalId: principalId
  }
}
```

My problem is figuring out how to define the scope, in both situations the error triggered on the scope is as follows:

attempt1:

- A resource's scope must match the scope of the Bicep file for it to be deployable. You must use modules to deploy resources to a different scope.bicep(BCP139)

attempt2:

- A resource's scope must match the scope of the Bicep file for it to be deployable. You must use modules to deploy resources to a different scope.bicep(BCP139)

Answer (score 0):

> How to deploy grant permissions on Self-Hosted IR using Bicep:-

To achieve your requirement, I modified your code as below and it worked as expected.

```bash
@description('The principal to assign the role to')
param  principalId  string = '283da8d3-c6ea-4f1e-b713-0b26f710775a'
@allowed([
'Owner'
'Contributor'
])
@description('Built-in role to assign')
param  builtInRoleType  string
var  role = {
Owner: '/subscriptions/${subscription().subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635'
Contributor: '/subscriptions/${subscription().subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c'
}
resource  df  'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories@2018-06-01'  existing = {
name: 'newdfsj'
}
resource  ir  'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/integrationRuntimes@2018-06-01'  existing = {
parent: df
name: 'newdfsj-managedVnetIr'
}
resource  roleAssign 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-04-01-preview' = {
name: guid(df.id,  principalId,  role[builtInRoleType])
properties: {
roleDefinitionId: role[builtInRoleType]
principalId: principalId
}
scope: ir
}
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

***Role assignment for the Integration runtime data factory scope is completed:***

[image]